# Which design pattern to use for my usecase?

Tags: database, design-patterns, ldap

My core usecase is to read/write from database and directory server.

Eg.
createUser,
modifyUser,
associateGroup,
changePassword etc

I have several other functionalities to be done in several of these use cases.
1.) audit start of operation
2.) audit failure in case of exception/error 
3.) validate data
4.) persist in db
5.) persist in directory server (LDAP)
6.) notify in somecases like password change
7.) audit success
8.) future something else

I am thinking of implementing this in some kind of decorator design pattern is there some better suggestions ???

Thanks,
Vignesh

Answer (score 0):

The data should have been validated long before you persist it.  Move that code up to where the service receives the request.

"Persist in DB" and "Persist in database server" are the same thing.  You're overcomplicating it.  Your comment suggests that you should prefer wording to distinguish between a relational database and a directory, but my conclusion doesn't change.

Notify for password change is a separate use case.

The only thing that qualifies is logging the start, completion, and error.  You can do this easily with an around aspect if you use a language or framework that supports AOP, like Spring.  It's a middle tier feature.

Comment: This requirement is for backend functionality and data validation is done again (first validation is in UI) to ensure data is proper. One of the persist i meant is for directory server (LDAP) and other is in database.

Comment: I agree that you need server side validation, above and beyond the UI stuff.  But it should be done when the request comes into the service.  I'm assuming that you aren't exposing your database to the network.

Comment: Its an EJB call where the request would come to from UI. From the EJB code is where all this is needed i.e. 1.) audit start of operation 2.) audit failure in case of exception/error 3.) validate data 4.) persist in db 5.) persist in directory server (LDAP) 6.) notify in somecases like password change etc. 7.) audit success

Comment: What duffy says, data should not reach ur database access layer when not valid.

Comment: The EJB ought to be doing validation and binding, and then asking something else to persist.  The one listening for the requests and the one doing the persisting are two completely separate objects.  Call to the database should never be made if data is invalid.  Your comment only repeats what you said and adds nothing.  My answer still stands.

Comment: I agree with u, what i am saying is that call to database will only be done after data is validated. No call to db will be done with invalid data